# Submit form with jQuery resets selected value

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using jQuery to submit a form when a User chooses an option from my Rails `<%= f.select %>` helper. It's working great, however when the form submits and my view renders the results, the option I selected resets to "Select". So I'm wondering: Is there a way to make it so if I select "Hello", "Hello" is shown as the option after the form is submitted?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(function(){
    $('select').live('change',function() {
        $(this).closest('form#index').submit();
    });
});
```

And here is my `select` form helper:

```
<%= f.select :profile_subject_eq, options_for_select([['Select'], ... ['Hello']]) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with Ruby, but in other server-side languages (e.g. asp.net) the problem might be that the postback routine is trying to apply submitted value to the select control before the select is filled with the list of options and thus no option is being selected.